# Alternatives to dynamically created input text fields

Tags: javascript, forms, input, textfield

I was previously using dynamically created input text fields on my form to allow a user to enter names of friends. However, on my redesign this form will be on top of an image inside a div and it'd look a bit rubbish if it extended out of that.

Are there any alternatives that allow the user to enter multiple names which look good within the confines of a background image?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a button for add friends and on clicking show a small lightbox that displays a single textfield and button. On adding each friend show the selected friend in the lightbox itself. Just like facebook does when you add friends for sending msgs ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Do you know of any good jQuery plugins for this?